# Log every operation of root user (and sudoers)

Tags: linux, logging

I want to log every operation of root on my server. This is useful for debugging, or for setting up another identical server, and so on. I am searching for a solution for either centos or debian. Preferably one that works on both.

It sould also cover every operation done via sudo.

What nearly fulfills my requirements is the **logging** function of **PuTTY**. The drawbacks are: it is saved on the client (should be on the server, since the clients may vary). Multiple ssh sessions are not well supported.

### Other ideas I looked into:

**.bash_history** is another idea. But it misses a time stamp and chronology is not maintained if multiple sessions are used. If a file is changed then only the command (e.g., `vim some-file.config`) is visible, bot not what has been changed.

**psacct** or **acct** have timestamps, but changes to files are still not visible.

If I understood **auditd** correctly, you need to specify what should be monitored. But I want to monitor everything (e.g., package installations, config file changes, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `script` command. I don't know if it writes a timestamp for every command, but for sure it writes every command into a server log. I use it as the first step to create a shell script.

You could start it via Putty or use it as login shell or if you are on the system just type `script`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Oh this looks interesting. Especially in combination wit the `scriptreplay` command. It would be nice to have FF/Play/Pause functionality like in a video for scriptreplay. But in total it looks very promissing. I still need to figure out how to run it automatically for root logins and sodo commands. And to have a look at how it handles multiple parallel sessions.